# Wordpress returning to post new page after publish

Tags: wordpress

After updating to wordpress 4.9.7, a strange issue comes up.
On publish, a new post page shows up. And what is even more strange is that the form data is not sent to post.php, but rather post-new.php.

Comment: When you have an unusual problem that seems unique to your system, temporarily deactivate all plugins.  If problem goes away, reactivate one by one testing inbetween.   When problem re-occurs then you'll know which plugin causes it.

Comment: Possibly related? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/236798/wordpress-redirects-me-to-homepage-after-page-update-in-admin-section

Comment: More possible? https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/42427/whenever-i-try-to-publish-a-post-in-wordpress-i-always-get-redirected-to-the-in